# Get new token google api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm building an extension for Google Chrome. The extension is a New Tab Page. 
Well to get user_email, what I do is get a token in javascript with this code:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive":true},function(token){
        console.log(token);
    });
```

And I do a request to have user email to this direction:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=(token)

My problem today, was that, trying something I revoked that token, and now my JavaScript console returns me an error saying that the token is invalid and can't do the petition to the userinfo url. I thought that if I clean cache and refresh the extension, the first code will generate a new token, but it was not until five minutes later  that the new token was generated.

I want to know how to force to get a new token immediately if the last one now is invalid.

(I apologize for my English :/ )

Thanks :)

Comment: You can call chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken to flush the token from the cache before you call getAuthToken again. To see the reference on the link: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken

Comment: I will try that! Thanks :) By the way do you know how to get the same information but offline?